# Proving asymptotic growth of function

Tags: functions, algorithms, notation, asymptotics

### Question

> $\text{Given,}\,\,f(n)=O( g(n)),\text{I have to check whether}\,g(n)=O(f(n)^2)$

#### My Approach

> $f(n)=O( g(n)) \Rightarrow f(n) \leq c\times g(n)\,\, \text{for some positive constant c}......(1)$
>
> I have to check $g(n)=O(f(n)^2) \Rightarrow g(n) \leq c\times f((n)^2)....(2)$

i think $g(n)=O(f(n)^2)$ holds because if it holds then from (1) and (2), i can derive transitive relation i.e

> $f(n)=O(f(n)^2) \Rightarrow f(n) \leq c\times f((n)^2)$

Also big-oh(O) holds Reflexive property.

Am i right?

Is there any other way to prove this.

Please help

Comment: It's not true, take $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=n^3$.

Comment: @LeeMosher thank you sir for pointing point my flaw .Can you please advice how to prove it without using example. :)

Comment: Since this counterexample proves that the statement you are trying to prove is false, I would recommend that you not attempt to prove it is true.

Comment: okk got it ,thanks :)

Comment: More generally, when faced with such a problem, try out simple examples.  In the current case, why not try examples where $g(n)=f(n)$ as a cheap way of guaranteeing the $f=O(g)$ hypothesis is met.  Then your question specializes to asking if $f=O(f^2)$, which can be tested with $f(n)=n$ and $f(n)=1/n$, say, resulting in another instant counterexample.

Comment: @kimchilover  okk  i will try to apply this next time ,thanks !